# Архитектура ВКонтакте

Tags: highload, вконтакте

В наше время я думаю многих разработчиков интересует какая-либо информация по разработке высоконагруженных (**highload**) веб-приложений — **ВКонтакте** отличный пример.

**Наверное самое простое:**

- как работает распределение нагрузки? Вот например, домен **vk.com** в секунду получает ~**100 000** запросов. (Наверное, обычный VPS не выдержит все-таки. :D) Так что дальше? Как это работает?
- как работают новости? Слышал про **`Dklab_Realplexor`**

Вопросы буду пополнять.

Comment: [10 известных масштабируемых архитектурных шаблонов](http://www.insight-it.ru/masshtabiruemost/10-izvestnykh-masshtabiruemykh-arkhitekturnykh-shablonov/)

Comment: в нескольких последних выпусках журнала "Хакер" были поверхностные статьи про highload

Comment: @Spectre, да, в последних шести. В каждом статья, посвященная тому или иному аспекту HighLoad.

Answer (score 3):

[Архитектура Вконтакте](http://www.insight-it.ru/masshtabiruemost/arkhitektura-vkontakte/).

Comment: Читал и не раз.

Comment: @exec вам сейчас это точно не нужно. Когда приложение доходит до такого уровня, то вопросы будут совершенно другие :)

Comment: @lampa, у меня сейчас запросы с join и в базе 1000 строк тупят) Так что я готовлюсь в самому плохому. Но AmazonAWS не далеко.

Answer (score 3):

Олег Бунин  оказал влияние на архитектуру Вконтакте. Послушайте подскасты, читайте про него или вообще посещайте семинары где он выступает. Некоторые вопросы он затрагивает. Суется почти на все семинары, рассказывает часто про вк. Так же можно ему лично задать вопрос (помню вопросов к нему обычно не много, поэтому имеет смысл)

Answer (score 1):

> Наверное, обычный VPS не выдержит
> все-таки. :D

XDD) ИМХО первым что должно было прийти в голову это собственный ЦОД [раз](http://telecombloger.ru/12126) [два](http://telecombloger.ru/12313), но никак убогий VPS) Можно погуглить и собрать больше информации из недр чем из ответов и комментов в этом топике!

Comment: Эти фотки видел еще во ВКонтакте, через час после публикации. Круто кстати, очень круто. Но у меня пока что нет средств осуществить вот такое.