# Структура социальных сетей

Tags: структуры, facebook, база-данных, вконтакте, соцсети

Меня вот интересует такой вопрос. Хочу создать социальную сеть, для домашнего пользования и практики. Вопрос такой:

Какова структура хранения данных в этих соц сетях в БД? Используются несколько таблиц или одна таблица и несколько столбцов для(статусов, имя, пароль, мейл, лайков, комментов, фоток, видео).

Как будет оптимально и умно? Использовать все в одном или внешние ключи использовать?

**UPDATE**

В чем суть:

Соц сеть довольно большой проект. И поэтому я думаю что там можно хорошенько потренироваться, набить навыки и лепить горку крупинками. Думаю так намного эффективнее будет.
Я хочу начать обучение PHP, JavaScript, SQL. Про каждое из них я немного знаю. Вот теперь хочу уже более серьезнее заняться этим, попрактиковаться и пойти дальше. В универе так и не научили толком ничему, кроме теории. Поэтому нет того мышления программиста. Думаю пора исправляться.

Comment: а поконкретней? Можно?

Comment: а так, основные данные пользователей в одной таблице, комменты в другой, медиаконтент можно в одну таблицу объединить, можно в разные.

Comment: и все же правда, что такое соц.сеть для домашнего пользования? :)

Comment: @thunder обновил вопрос )

Comment: Уже существует похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/185391/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5
Возможно, там ты найдешь нужную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

там используются разные типы БД под разные задачи

староватая статья, но все в одном :) [Как устроен facebook и vkontakte](http://masterpro.ws/forum/18-obo-vsem-kurilka/616-kak-ustroeny-facebook-i-vkontakte)
много чего изменилось, но общую картину показывает... Нет одной БД. Нет использования только одного ЯП.

Вообщем нужно гуглить. Больше искать про HighLoad или не прицеливаться на эти сети, там все сложно очень.

Comment: для дома highload?

Comment: нет, в образовательных целях, и отвечал больше про мордокнигу и вконтактик и то, что сравнивать домашнюю сетку и мировые сети и на основе их архитектуры чтото делать, несколько бессмысленно. :)

Comment: угу, вопрос был про оптимально и умно в целях обучения программированию, а наверное не "как админить парк из десятков тысяч серваков и менять винты по пять штук в день"... то, что используют вконтакт и фейсбук - это от "плохой" жизни. ну не справляется умный и оптимальный sql с таким объемом данных, ну так это в частности не повод отказываться от sql вообще где бы то ни было. пой поинт в том, что "хайлоад" и "умно и оптимально" лежат в разных плоскостях знаний.

Comment: мне вот взять 1000 пользователей, и то для того, чтобы научиться еще и с нагрузкой SQL повозиться. А так, я согласен с @Yura Ivanov

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая соцсеть - диаспора. Для нее есть [сорцы](https://diasporafoundation.org/get_involved). Можно скачать, смотреть, развернуть для себя. Код на руби.

Comment: Странно у них на сайте с русским языком :)

Comment: да можно просто [погуглить][1] :) но ТС хочет сам написать как я понял, поэтому разьорки в коде готовых соц-сетей тот еще гемор и просто так структуру ты нифига не поймешь.

[1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=скрипты+социальных+сетей

Comment: Да, я хочу с нуля все. Сесть, задумать что то, погуглить, почитать и творить. После творения посидеть и подумать об оптимизации набранного ранее кода. Но так сидеть и разобраться в чужом коде - уйма потерянного времени

Comment: иногда изобретать велосипед полезно, но часто нужно посмотреть, как изобретают его другие, тогда можно изобретать велосипеды значительно быстрее. И тогда значительно больше шансов, что один из них поедет и принесет как минимум удовольствие, а как оптимум - какие то дивиденды.

Comment: Но на данный момент у меня недостаточно знаний для этого. Может чуть позже, для оптимизации