# Распределение нагрузки php

Tags: php, highload

Всем привет. Занимаюсь сейчас созданием крупного сайта на php, и встал вопрос, как в сайтах типа вконтакта реализована архитектура. Насколько я знаю, вконтакте умудряется работать на десятках серверах. Так вот, каким образом разложить сайт на несколько серверов ?

Comment: А где вы такое читали? про сервере с лайками и пр? За лайки отвечает 2-3 запроса к БД. Неужели на это нужен целый сервер?

Comment: Возможно я что-то путаю, и у них база данных распределена по серверам ?

Comment: У них все распределено. Вопрос сам по себе годный, но надо понимать, что если человек не обладает скиллом набрать в гугле слова "архитектура вконтакте", но при этом собирается написать что-то подобное, то встает вопрос о степни адекватности, с которой он оценивает окружающую его реальность.

Comment: [вопрос с ru.so про соцсети и производительность](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/292751/5079), библиотеки видео: [с конференции highload](https://vimeo.com/ontico/videos), [техномаркет майл.ру](https://www.youtube.com/user/TPMGTU/videos) (есть несколько видео про highload), сайты про highload: [архитектура различных крупных сайтов/соцсетей](https://www.insight-it.ru/), [Оптимизация и масштабирование Web приложений](http://ruhighload.com/) + [конференция по highload](http://www.highload.ru/) (и вроде их ["Продуманная оптимизация"](http://optimization.guide/))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ресурсы любого сервера конечны. Каждое соединение с клиентом потребляет память, процессор, часть сетевого канала. Поэтому если у вас огромное количество пользователей и соединений, стараются задействовать несколько серверов, распределив между ними нагрузку.

Первое, что приходит в голову, это разделить статические файлы (CSS, JavaScript), приложение и базу данных. Размещаем их для начала на разных серверах.

1. Далее, увеличиваем группировку серверов для статических файлов, выделяя для них отдельный домен, можно либо поставить балансировщик перед ними, либо назначать каждому из серверов собственный поддомен, выбирая их в случайном порядке приложением. Если возрастает нагрузка на статику, вы просто увеличиваете количество серверов в пуле статики.
2. Далее масштабируем сервер приложения – тоже увеличиваем их группировку. Вы не можете себе позволить хранить медиа-файлы пользователя на этом же самом сервере, иначе загрузив аватарку на один сервер, вам придется распространить её на все сервера вашего пула. Если их сотни – вы забъете все каналы пересылкой. Поэтому все медиафайлы – храним на отдельных серверах, лучше в каком-нибудь безразмерном хранилище (Swift, S3, Ceph). В этом случае на всех серверах с вашим приложением будет только код и их количество так же можно наращивать, выравнивая нагрузку балансировщиком.
3. Далее база данных – это самое сложное место. Обычно любая база данных имеет механизм репликации, когда вы соединяете базы данных в цепочку, записывая данные в один сервер (мастер) по механизму репликации она воспроизводится на всех подчиненных серверах (слейв). Проблемы тут две: информация воспроизводится с некоторой задержкой с одной стороны, с другой – так вы масштабируете только операцию чтения, запись не масштабируется. Если у вас небольшое количество пользователей, которые пишут – вы еще сможете существовать с одним мастером, если их миллионы — запись следует масштабировать по-другому. Механизмов несколько: репликация по типу кольца, когда вы объединяете в кольцо несколько мастер-серверов, скажем 10 и каждый десятый id-ник пишите на свой индивидуальный сервер, который разносится по остальным мастер-серверам репликацией (в живую такой механизм не видел – очень геморройно по многим причинам). Можно вычислять хэш пользователя, например, по его имени и распределять пользователей по разным серверам, например, у вас 256 серверов базы данных, вычисляем md5-хэш пользователя, берем первые два символа хэша – их как раз будет 256 серверов. Всех пользователей с подходящим хэшем можно обслуживать выделенным сервером базы данных. Обычно, правда, стараются выбрать механизм который распределяет пользователей более равномерно.
4. Дальше начинают выделять отдельные модули приложения в сервисы – рекламой занимается свой пул серверов, комментариями – свой, новостями – свой, счетчики – свой.

Только за ранее этого лучше не делать, лишь в том случае если видна нагрузка на подсистему: если у вас 3 баннера, вам не нужна отдельная подсистема, если вам не нужны счетчики реального времени вам не нужна отдельная система для них. Только потратите время и усилия. Однако, спроектировать приложение, чтобы у него база данных, сервер приложения, статика и медиа-файлы могли обслуживаться разными серверами, а лучше пулами серверов – дело хорошее.